# Применение изменений в реестре без перезагрузки

Tags: c++builder, winapi, реестр, c++

Много где обсуждалась данная тема, но так ничего и не работает.

```
SendMessage (HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)
TEXT("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\DreamScene")));
SendMessage (HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM) TEXT("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\Desktop")));
DWORD_PTR dwResult;
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0, SMTO_NORMAL ||
SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG ||SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG, 1, &dwResult);
```

Изменения должны применяться для программы DreamScene (видео-обои) и для смены обоев рабочего стола.
К сожалению, ни один из приведенных способов не работает. Убийство проводника не предлагать!

Comment: Вы всех оповещаете об изменении ключей, и непонятно чего, но кому это интересно?

Comment: Ваш код может быть и сработает, если эта самая программа действительно слушает изменения в `WindowProc`. Вы уверены, что она так делает?

Comment: Explorer.exe должен увидеть изменения в реестре без перезагрузки, позволить установить видеообои либо обычные. Я не знаю, реагирует ли программа на сообщения, но ведь и обычные обои рабочего стола не устанавливаются без ресета. Может, есть универсальный рабочий способ, как обходиться без рестарта? Другие программы же умеют такое делать, значит, все возможно. Почему за столько лет ничего дельного на форумах нет, не могу понять.

Comment: DreamScene применяет видео в качестве обоев рабочего стола по нажатию контекстного меню проводника "Set as background". Может, как-то можно эмулировать нажатие на это меню?

Comment: @4lice: А сменить обои без `DreamScene` у вас получается? (Если нет, возможно, ошибка где-то ещё.)

Comment: Обычные обои реагируют на изменения, когда посылаю им сообщения.

Comment: @4lice: Тогда, значит, вы посылаете сообщение правильно, но только DreamScene эти сообщения игнорирует. Имеет полное право, кстати. Выясняйте у разработчиков DreamScene.